# How do I compare two Range objects?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two Range variables. How can I make sure that they belong to the same Sheet and reference the same set of cells?

For example:

```
var mySheet = // ...
function onEdit(e) {
  var range1 = e.range;
  var range2 = mySheet.getRange(123, 234);
  if (areEqual(range1, range2)) {
    // cell (123, 234) was edited,
    // let's do stuff
  }
}
```

What should I write instead of `areEqual`?

Comment: Should I change anything to make this more googleable?

Comment: It is a very specific and to-the-point question (which is good!). I can't see anything that would make it more visible. BTW, welcome to Web Applications!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of checking row, column, width and height, you can just compare the A1 notations (like `A1:B2`), in combination with something that identifies the sheet:

```
function areEqual(r1, r2) {
  return r1.getGridId() === r2.getGridId()
    && r1.getA1Notation() === r2.getA1Notation()
}
```

[`range.getGridId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getgridid) uniquely identifies a sheet the range belongs to (within a spreadsheet).

See the documentation for the [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object, and the [`getA1Notation()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation) and [`getGridId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getgridid) in particular.

---

You can shorten it even further by just comparing [`range.getDataSourceUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataSourceUrl()):

```
function areEqual(r1, r2) {
  return r1.getDataSourceUrl() === r2.getDataSourceUrl()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use this until I find a better solution:

```
function areEqual(r1, r2) {
  return r1.getSheet().getName() == r2.getSheet().getName() 
         && r1.getRow() == r2.getRow() 
         && r1.getColumn() == r2.getColumn()
         && r1.getWidth() == r2.getWidth()
         && r1.getHeight() == r2.getHeight();
}
```

(`r1.getSheet() == r2.getSheet()` doesn't work, same as `range1 == range2` in the original post.)